# Word order of clauses in this sentence

Tags: word-order

I wrote:

> As was discussed before, to specify an anchor, in addition to the content, one may use stable and semantic labels used for some tag's attributes such as  *id* and *class name* (e.g. "main" value for the main division of a page).

I used some clauses separated by comma. First, I would like to know if comma was applied correctly? Second, is it natural to have such orders?

Comment: The meaning is not clear, so it's hard to answer the question about the comma placement.  Why is "in addition to the content" where it is?  Is it apposite "anchor"?  Is the content specified?  What do you mean by "specify"?

Comment: Or is "content" used in addition to stable semantic labels, for something?

Comment: @TRomano yes in addition to attributes, something like *One may specify an anchor by utilizing, in addition to the element's content, stable and semantic labels of specific tag's attributes such as id and classname.* It was suggested by another member, couldn't use "in addition to " like I did in my sentence?

Comment: @TRomano I wanted somehow emphasize "in addition to content" which is regarded as the default feature, one can specify an anchor using attributes...

Comment: @TRomano or maybe I should use "besides the main content, one may specify ...." or even "apart from the main content, one may specify ...."?